# FromQuery dictionary mirrors all query parameters when a matching parameter is not present in query

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, model-binding

I have the following ASP.net Core MVC controller:

```cs
namespace Mugen.API
{
    [Route("api")]
    public class ApiController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("search")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SearchAsync(
            [FromQuery] int skip,
            [FromQuery] int pageSize,
            [FromQuery] [CanBeNull] string searchTerm,
            [FromQuery] [CanBeNull] Dictionary<string, List<string>> filters
        )
        {
           // ...
        }
    }
}
```

When I make for example a request to the url

`http://localhost/api/search?skip=0&pageSize=20&filters=`

or

`http://localhost/api/search?skip=0&pageSize=20&filters[Param][0]=value`

binding of the parameters works as expected.

However, if I don't supply a the `filters` param explicitly, i.e

`http://localhost/api/search?skip=0&pageSize=20`

I'm getting all the parameters populated as expected, except for the dictionary, which gets the values

```json
{{"skip": ["0"]}, {"pageSize":["20"]}}
```

populated in the dictionary, which is not the request the user intended. This is done in addition to the other parameters getting populated (sort of mirroring).

I'm using `.net Core 3.1` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.2.0`

Comment: Hi @Mugen,any update about this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use binding prefix，change your code like below:

```
[HttpGet("search")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SearchAsync(
        [FromQuery] int skip,
        [FromQuery] int pageSize,
        [FromQuery] string searchTerm,
        [FromQuery][Bind(Prefix = "filters")] Dictionary<string, List<string>> filters
    )
```

Comment: Do you perhaps know to explain the default behavior of this mirrored binding in the first place?